# Clarification on $duplicateChecks

Tags: php, silverstripe

I would like to clarify if I interpret how `$duplicateChecks` work. I extended the CsvBulkLoader class as follows:

```
class UserCsvBulkLoader extends CsvBulkLoader{

public $hasHeaderRow = true;

public $columnMap = [
'UserID'    =>  'UserID',
'FirstName' =>  'FirstName',
'LastName'  =>  'LastName',
'Email'     =>  'Email',
'Username'  =>  'Username'
];

public $duplicateChecks = [
'Email'     =>  'Email'
];

}
```

I use this in my `UserLogin` DataObject where I have current records. For example I have 1 row with information: `1234,"John","Doe","j.doe@example.com","jodoe"`. Now if I upload a csv file containing information such as `1234,"John","Doe","j.doe@example.com","jodoe25"`, why is it that my current records gets updated. Should the $duplicateChecks just return the existing record and not update it? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after checking and doing some experiments, the `$duplicateChecks` is used in `findExistingObject()` method in the `CsvBulkLoader` class. Now, `findExistingObject()` method is used in `processRecord()` method to check if an object exist. If yes, then the object/row in the record will not be duplicated but updated by default.

In case I want this object not duplicated nor updated then I need to override the `processRecord()` method in case it finds a matching object(i.e. a duplicate) and just skip it. This is the current solution I could use for this scenario but maybe there's a better way.